# Simple JOIN query but I can't duplicate results as they are supposed to return in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I want to return an outer join on two tables, regions and product_region_list, limiting the result to a single product id, eg:

```html
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=348 style='border-collapse:
     collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:261pt'>
  <col width=116 span=3 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:3712;
     width:87pt'>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 width=116 style='height:16.0pt;width:87pt'><strong>regions table</strong>
      </td>
      <td width=116 style='width:87pt'></td>
      <td width=116 style='width:87pt'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>region_id</td>
      <td class=xl65>region_name</td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>1</td>
      <td class=xl65>Africa</td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>2</td>
      <td class=xl65>Americas</td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>3</td>
      <td class=xl65>Asia</td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>4</td>
      <td class=xl65>Europe</td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 colspan=2 style='height:16.0pt;mso-ignore:colspan'><strong>product_region_list table</strong>
      </td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>prl_id</td>
      <td class=xl65>product_id</td>
      <td class=xl65>region_id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>1</td>
      <td class=xl65>123</td>
      <td class=xl65>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>2</td>
      <td class=xl65>234</td>
      <td class=xl65>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>3</td>
      <td class=xl65>234</td>
      <td class=xl65>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>4</td>
      <td class=xl65>234</td>
      <td class=xl65>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>5</td>
      <td class=xl65>234</td>
      <td class=xl65>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'></td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 colspan=2 style='height:16.0pt;mso-ignore:colspan'><strong>desired result where product_id=123</strong>
      </td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>r.region_id</td>
      <td class=xl65>prl.region_id</td>
      <td class=xl65>r.region_name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>1</td>
      <td class=xl65>1</td>
      <td class=xl65>Africa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>2</td>
      <td class=xl65>null</td>
      <td class=xl65>Americas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>3</td>
      <td class=xl65>null</td>
      <td class=xl65>Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>4</td>
      <td class=xl65>null</td>
      <td class=xl65>Europe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 colspan=3 style='height:16.0pt;mso-ignore:colspan'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 colspan=2 style='height:16.0pt;mso-ignore:colspan'>

<strong>desired result where product_id=234</strong>

      </td>
      <td class=xl65></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>r.region_id</td>
      <td class=xl65>prl.region_id</td>
      <td class=xl65>r.region_name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>1</td>
      <td class=xl65>1</td>
      <td class=xl65>Africa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>2</td>
      <td class=xl65>2</td>
      <td class=xl65>Americas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>3</td>
      <td class=xl65>3</td>
      <td class=xl65>Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height=21 style='height:16.0pt'>
      <td height=21 class=xl65 style='height:16.0pt'>4</td>
      <td class=xl65>4</td>
      <td class=xl65>Europe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried to copy solutions that purport to do exactly as I am trying to obtain, but the result I get for product_id=123 is only the first row (ie no nulls where there is no region_id match) or for product_id=234 it gives me 16 rows instead of four. Is there a setting I need to change so MySQL will interpret my query correctly?

Here is one of MANY queries I've tried that seemed to produce the correct result for others, but not for me:

```
SELECT R.region_id, PRL.region_id, R.region_name
   FROM regions R
        LEFT OUTER JOIN product_region_list PRL
        ON PRL.region_id = R.region_id 
  WHERE PRL.product_id=234;
```

Comment: I think that'd greatly depend on what your actual MySQL query _is_...?

Comment: I've tried a million queries none works

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong with your query without seeing it. Please attach it to question.

Comment: added a query at bottom, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WHERE clause specifies a column from the LEFT OUTER JOINed table, which effectively results in an INNER JOIN.

Move the WHERE clause check to the ON clause:-

```
SELECT R.region_id, PRL.region_id, R.region_name
FROM regions R
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_region_list PRL
ON PRL.region_id = R.region_id 
AND PRL.product_id=234;
```